# Strange Outputs? User-Defined Class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, output

I have to create a sphere class with the following attributes:

> Write a class Sphere with the following properties:
>
> Private attributes:         (1) X, Y, Z coordinates of the center       (2)
>   Radius
>
> Accessor and mutator methods to
>   • Set and get the X, Y, and Z
>   coordinates
>   • Set and get the radius
>   • Get the volume and surface
>   area if a sphere.
>
> For a sphere,
>   Volume = 4πr3/3
>   Surface Area = 4πr2
>   Write a main
>   program to test the sphere class.

I have never worked with classes before. I think I did this correctly. However, my output for my Volume and my Surface Area comes out really strange. Below is my program and my output.

**PROGRAM**

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Sphere {
private:
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Z;
    float R;
    float Volume;
    float SurfaceArea;
public:
    float DefineCoordinates(float x, float y, float z);
    void DefineRadius(float radius);
    double GetVolume()
    {
        return (((4 * M_PI*pow(R, 3))) / 3);
    }
    double GetSurfaceArea()
    {
        return (4 * M_PI*pow(R, 2));
    }
    float GetX();
    float GetY();
    float GetZ();


};

float Sphere::GetX() {
    return X;
}

float Sphere::GetY() {
    return Y;
}

float Sphere::GetZ() {
    return Z;
}

float Sphere::DefineCoordinates(float x, float y, float z) {
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Z = z;
    return 0;
}

void Sphere::DefineRadius(float radius) {
    R = radius;
}


int main() {
    float inputr, radius, x, y, z;
    Sphere sphere;
    double Volume = sphere.GetVolume();
    double SurfaceArea = sphere.GetSurfaceArea();
    char open = '(';
    char close = ')';
    char comma = ',';
    cout << "Please input the center of the sphere in the fashion (X,Y,Z) and press enter: ";
    cin >> open >> x >> comma >> y >> comma >> z >> close;
    cout << "Please define the radius of the sphere: ";
    cin >> inputr;
    sphere.DefineCoordinates(x, y, z);
    sphere.DefineRadius(inputr);
    cout << "This sphere has a center of (" << sphere.GetX() << ", " << sphere.GetY() << ", " << sphere.GetZ() << ")." << endl;
    cout << "This sphere has a radius of " << inputr << "." << endl;
    cout << "This computes to a volume of " << Volume << " units cubed, and a surface area of " << SurfaceArea << "." << endl;
}
```

**OUTPUT**
No matter what I input as radius, I will get:

> This computes to a volume of -5.18547e+24 units cubed, and a surface
>   area of 1.4488e+17.

What am I doing wrong?? Also, any other advice to clean up my class would be helpful!

Comment: You calculate/call `Volume` and `SurfaceArea` before coordinates and R are initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the GetVolume() method too early. Call it after actually taking the radius from the user.

```
int main() {
float inputr, radius, x, y, z;
Sphere sphere;
double SurfaceArea = sphere.GetSurfaceArea();
char open = '(';
char close = ')';
char comma = ',';
cout << "Please input the center of the sphere in the fashion (X,Y,Z) and press enter: ";
cin >> open >> x >> comma >> y >> comma >> z >> close;
cout << "Please define the radius of the sphere: ";
cin >> inputr;
sphere.DefineCoordinates(x, y, z);
sphere.DefineRadius(inputr);
double Volume = sphere.GetVolume();
cout << "This sphere has a center of (" << sphere.GetX() << ", " << sphere.GetY() << ", " << sphere.GetZ() << ")." << endl;
cout << "This sphere has a radius of " << inputr << "." << endl;
cout << "This computes to a volume of " << Volume << " units cubed, and a surface area of " << SurfaceArea << "." << endl;
}
```

Like the above.

Answer (score 1):

Simple,
You read the volume and the surface before defining the radius.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you are calling the `GetVolume()` and `GetSurfaceArea()` functions before you are reading the input. Your calculations are based on uninitialized values.

You should move the functions calls after the calls of `DefineCoordinates()`and `DefineRadius()`

Your main should look similar to this:

```
int main() {
    float inputr, radius, x, y, z;
    Sphere sphere;
    char open = '(';
    char close = ')';
    char comma = ',';
    cout << "Please input the center of the sphere in the fashion (X,Y,Z) and press enter: ";
    cin >> open >> x >> comma >> y >> comma >> z >> close;
    cout << "Please define the radius of the sphere: ";
    cin >> inputr;
    sphere.DefineCoordinates(x, y, z);
    sphere.DefineRadius(inputr);
    double Volume = sphere.GetVolume();
    double SurfaceArea = sphere.GetSurfaceArea();
    cout << "This sphere has a center of (" << sphere.GetX() << ", " << sphere.GetY() << ", " << sphere.GetZ() << ")." << endl;
    cout << "This sphere has a radius of " << inputr << "." << endl;
    cout << "This computes to a volume of " << Volume << " units cubed, and a surface area of " << SurfaceArea << "." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sphere` has a default constructor, which does not initialize the `X`, `Y` and `Z` members. Directly after construction, you try to calculate the volume and surface from these indefinite values.

In other words,

```
double Volume = sphere.GetVolume();
```

does not define a mathematical relation (it seems you think it does), it's an imperative. The volume will be calculated once (used for initialization of `Volume`) and its value will not change with you changing `sphere`'s attributes. Do this calculation **after** you've called `Sphere::DefineCoordinates` and `Sphere::DefineRadius`.

---

Or, make it impossible to construct such an invalid `Sphere` object. Learn how to use constructors, and use some `const` qualifiers from time to time.

For completeness, what are `Sphere::Volume` and `Spehre::SurfaceArea` for? Why does `Sphere::DefineCoordinates` return a `float` (always `0`) and why is my answer not at the top?

Comment: How do I remedy this? I'm not sure I understand.